# Joystick servo control axis value when idle (unity)

Tags: unity, controllers

When the joystick servo control is idle (user not moving it) , i don't believe the axis value will be 0 because there's a lot of thing that interfere with the value (such as calibration , inaccuracy , physics problem in real life , ect . . ) . Is anybody have tested at which range the joystick servo control axis value is safe to be considered as idle? (both negative and positive) . I'm looking for constants here.

To anyone confused what does i meant with joystick servo control , picture below :
(ps : not my image, i found it on google)

[image: joystick servo control]

Comment: Unfortunately, this varies substantially between different controller hardware, and even with the age/wear level of each device. Games that had a safe deadzone for a new console at launch can sometimes exhibit significant drift a decade later on well-loved controllers. So there's not a hard cutoff "this value is safe" so much as a gradient of confidence/probability, depending on the range of factors at play for your target devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is why the unity input system supplies built-in functionality to  define **deadzones**.

A deadzone is an area in which the stick's value will be clamped to its closest extreme (0-1).

A standard deadzone is usually under 15% tilt and over 95% tilt. You are of course free to change this however you wish.